# Todo List Application Code in Pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'd highly appreciate it if you can:

- Spot flaws, especially bad practices and suggest a possible alternative method.
- Spot inefficiencies and suggest how to perform that task efficiently.
- You may review my HTML/CSS as well.

```js
var addRecordFormVisibility = false;
var addRecordForm = document.getElementById('addRecord');
var addRecordFormButton = document.getElementById('submit');
var errors = document.getElementById('errors');
var addRecordFormTrigger = document.getElementById('addRecordFormTrigger');

function prepare() {
    addRecordForm.style.display="none";
}

function triggerAddRecordForm() {
    if(addRecordFormVisibility === false) {
        addRecordForm.style.display="block";
        addRecordFormVisibility = true;
    } else {
        addRecordForm.style.display="none";
        addRecordFormVisibility = false;
    }
}

function submit(event) {
    var userInput = document.getElementById('description').value;

    errors.innerHTML = '';

    if(userInput.length === 0) {
        errors.innerHTML = "Please fill in the form!";
    } else {
        var listItem = document.createElement('li');
        listItem.innerHTML = userInput;

        document.getElementById('todoList').appendChild(listItem);
    }

    event.preventDefault();
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", prepare, false);
addRecordFormButton.addEventListener("click", submit, false);
addRecordFormTrigger.addEventListener("click", triggerAddRecordForm, false);
```

```css
#todoApplication {
    width: 800px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #EEEEEE;
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
}
#errors {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>JavaScript</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="todoApplication">
            <button id="addRecordFormTrigger">Trigger Add Record Form</button>
            <div id="errors">

            </div>
            <form id="addRecord" method="POST">
                <input id="description" type="text" name="description" placeholder="Enter the task here">

                <button id="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
            <ul id="todoList"></ul>
        </div>

        <script src="src/TodoApp.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seeing what it does, I think "trigger" should be "toggle" instead ;-)

Comment: Yeah. I forgot that word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so, your code is overall looking nice, but a few changes could be made:

---

It's important to make sure you leave whitespace around your operators, like:

> ```
> addRecordForm.style.display="none";
>                            ^^
> ```

Could use whitespace around the operators.

---

I try not to suggest ternaries very often, but I believe that `triggerAddRecordForm` could be simplified with the use of one.

> ```
> function triggerAddRecordForm() {
>     if(addRecordFormVisibility === false) {
>         addRecordForm.style.display="block";
>         addRecordFormVisibility = true;
>     } else {
>         addRecordForm.style.display="none";
>         addRecordFormVisibility = false;
>     }
> }
> ```

into:

```
function triggerAddRecordForm() {
    addRecordForm.style.display = addRecordFormVisiblity ? "none" : "block";
    addRecordFormVisibility = !addRecordFormVisibility;
}
```

On the subject of `triggerAddRecordForm()`, in general you shouldn't compare to `false`, then `else` it. You should leave the check empty (checks if the variable is `true`) like so:

```
if(addRecordFormVisibility) {
    doStuff();
} else {
    doOtherStuff();
}
```

---

In `submit()`, you could improve `errors.innerHTML = ''`.
Why don't you just set `errors` to `document.getElementById('errors').innerHTML` instead, seeing as you don't use `errors` other than for that?

In `submit()` you should also improve your line spacing as well, as it seems a little strange.